# CPLEX folder can not find

Tags: cplex, opl

I installed CPLEX IBM ILOG last week with academia edition and I was trying to solve first code. But always facing the problem of not finding the folder. I have tried to run as administrator and also try to change the language or to locate the workspace in a different location, However, it is still not working. 
I am waiting for your help
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the actual and full error message? It seems you were able to start the IDE, so it seems a bit weird that CPLEX could not be found. What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1):

In documentation IDE and OPL > Starting Kit > Globalization you may read about what is not supported with regards to globalization.

Can you try not to use special characters in the paths and names? On top of the g "Altug", I see something that could hurt.